# C# Detect if an Iphone plug-in 

Tags: c#, iphone, windows, detect

I'm developing in VS2010/C#..
Can anyone please help me to figure how can I detect when Iphone plug in??

I've tried this

```
System.IO.DriveInfo[] drives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        try
        {


            foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo drive in drives)
            {
                if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
                    do something
                }
            }
```

But DriveType.Removable not includes the Iphone device,
It seems that the Iphone is "Internal Storage" and not a removable device...

Thank you all for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/15/how-can-i-determine-which-usb-devices-are-connected-to-a-computer.aspx